# Getting [Trying to get property of non-object] when using ->

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get fruits:

```
'target' => '{"fruits":{"serves":[{"value":["apple"],"option":"first"}],"excludes":[{"value":["タグ2"],"option":"first"}]}}',
```

My code:

```
$target = $request->target;
$fruits = $target->fruits; //getting "Trying to get property of non-object" here
```

I tried `json_decode($target->fruits)` and `$target['fruits']`, but I got error again.
What I do to get that fruits??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
$target = $request->target
```

will return a string. you have to convert it into json obj.

for that you have to use `json_decode();`

```
$target = $request->target;
$targetJson = json_decode($target);
$fruits = $targetJson['fruits'];
```

try this, hope this will help you.

Comment: this answer was 99% perfect!! But I couldnt get fruits usings  $targetJson->fruits, but $targetJson['fruits'] worked!! Thanks

Comment: try this as well, $targetJson['fruits']

Comment: ohh. I had this confusion, thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

you're getting value as in Multidimensional  array so it'll be in array.

```
$targetarray = json_decode($request->target);

print_r($targetarray['fruits']);
    exit;
```

**OR**

```
print_r($target[0]['fruits']);
exit;
```

Comment: `$target` is a string. how can this loop works on strings?